# jquery adding a row at the bottom of a table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am adding some rows into my table but right now this row it is going to **the top** instead of the **bottom** of the table.

I tried use `find("tr:last")` but still broken, can someone help on this?  thank you.

http://plnkr.co/edit/YaYihiOAS0C0wsyzUeat?p=preview

css:

```
  div.addRow {
      line-height: 45px;
      background-color: #fff;
      padding-left: 10px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid;
      border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    }
```

html:

```
 <table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>order</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>country</th>
        <th>action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>


  <table id="newRow" style="display:none">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
            <option value="1">option 1</option>
            <option value="2">option 2</option>
            <option value="2">option 3</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>DVap
        </td>
        <td>
          www</td>
        <td><i class="fa fa-pencil-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

      var table;

      $("#example").on("mousedown", "td .fa.fa-minus-square", function(e) {
        table.row($(this).closest("tr")).remove().draw();
      })

      $("#example").on('mousedown.edit', "i.fa.fa-pencil-square", function(e) {

        $(this).removeClass().addClass("fa fa-envelope-o");
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr").off("mousedown");
        var $tds = $row.find("td").not(':first').not(':last');

        $.each($tds, function(i, el) {
          var txt = $(this).text();
          $(this).html("").append("<input type='text' value=\"" + txt + "\">");
        });

      });

      $("#example").on('mousedown', "input", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
      });

      $("#example").on('mousedown.save', "i.fa.fa-envelope-o", function(e) {

        $(this).removeClass().addClass("fa fa-pencil-square");
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var $tds = $row.find("td").not(':first').not(':last');

        $.each($tds, function(i, el) {
          var txt = $(this).find("input").val()
          $(this).html(txt);
        });
      });


      $("#example").on('mousedown', "#selectbasic", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
      });


      var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ccTtqmPbkO?indent=2';
      table = $('#example').DataTable({
        ajax: url,
        rowReorder: {
          dataSrc: 'place',
          selector: 'tr'
        },
        columns: [{
          data: 'place'
        }, {
          data: 'name'
        }, {
          data: 'order'
        }, {
          data: 'delete'
        }]
      });

      $('#example').css('border-bottom', 'none');
      $('<div class="addRow"><button id="addRow">Add New Row</button></div>').insertAfter('#example');

      // add row
      $('#addRow').click(function() {
        //t.row.add( [1,2,3] ).draw();
        var rowHtml = $("#newRow").find("tr")[0].outerHTML
        console.log(rowHtml);
        table.row.add($(rowHtml)).draw();
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to `DataTables` [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()), the position of added row is determined by ordering and filtering applied to the table.

> The rows that are added are subjected to the ordering and search criteria that are applied to the table, which will determine the new row's position and visibility in the table.

You can assign specific ordering to `DataTable`:

```
table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ...,
    order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
    ...
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pzW71PqUrjnJF0kSmnws?p=preview) is example with changed ordering.

Comment: thank you, works well, do you know why my rowReorder is not working ?

Comment: I don't know much about `rowReorder` property but I think it just enables ability to change row position by drag&drop. However it does not specify ordering and does not affect position of newly added row. Somebody with more knowledge may correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
  bSort: false,
  ...
  ..
});
```

If you set `bSort` parameter into `false`, the newly appended row will be placed at the bottom. This is because when adding a row, it will refer on which sorting criteria your table is currently in (either `'Asc'` or `'Desc'`).

If you want to keep the sorting functionality, just set the default sorting into descending, by adding the option `order`.

```
$("#example").DataTable({
  "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
  ...
  ..
})
```

Comment: this breaks my sorting in the top of the table

Comment: I updated my answer, you can either set the default ordering to `desc` to keep the sorting functionality.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `append` instead `add`

```
$('#example').find( 'tbody' ).append( rowHtml).draw();
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/KQnOWCDGLI8MzKFfEnAS?p=preview

Comment: This method will actually do the trick, however, the newly appended row won't be added to the DataTable - that means, the rows count will not change and the appended data is also not searchable.